# How does a traditional CC/CV circuit work?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, constant-current, power-output-stage

I went through an application note from Texas Instruments referenced as snva829 ( the link http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva829/snva829.pdf  page 2 and 3) where they have discussed superficially the traditional CC/CV circuit.
Below is the circuit from [TI application report SNVA829 *How to Design a Simple Constant Current/Constant Voltage Buck Converter*](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva829/snva829.pdf):

> [image: schematic]
>
> The converter requires a sense
>   resistor (R_SENSE), an amplifier and a voltage regulation circuit (V_z). The current flowing through R_SENSE sets
>   the voltage across R_FB , which is the feedback voltage of a controller. In this way, the current is regulated.
>   As R_OUT increases, the voltage on the output rises to a point where the Zener diode conducts, and the
>   device transitions from a CC converter to a CV converter.

My questions are:

1. I understand that the Zener diode limits (clamps) the output voltage, but I did 
   not understand how does this circuit limits the output current ?
2. What is the role of the PNP transistor in the circuit ?
3. What is the relationship between Isense and Ifb ?
4. How does the output of OPAMP drives the base of the PNP transistor ?

Comment: hey! Can you tell us what the source of that circuit is? That kind of context might help understand it. Albeit you say "traditional", I've not seen this specific one before.

Comment: here is the link http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva829/snva829.pdf

Comment: um, the paragraphs surrounding that Fig. 1 already explain what this circuit does pretty well. What do you *not* understand?

Comment: Read my questions please !

Comment: Re: 1. I don't understand what you don't understand: the Zener, as you say, limits the voltage across it. Which is *exactly* the voltage between the output voltage and the feedback voltage. When the feedback voltage gets high, the SMPS reduces Vin (that's the control loop – and you're the control loop expert!)

Comment: Re: 2 to conduct current when the voltage across R_sense is large, thereby pulling up the feedback voltage

Comment: 3. and 4. are totally unclear to me. It's just literally "read the schematic and simulate it" for 3, and for 4. the base is directly attached to the opamp, so no idea what the doubt here is.

Comment: How does the sense circuit composed of Rsense and OPAMP affects the collector current of the transistor ? i.e how does the transistor respond to Isense ?

Comment: you know what an opamp does, right? (serious question, not meant to be rude!)

Comment: Generally speaking; when the OPAMP is in an open loop configuration, Vout=A(V+-V-) and when it is in a closed loop, (negative or positive feedback) the output voltage is scaled by a gain dependent to the combination of the resistors. In the ciruict, they have used a PNP transistor and a PNP transistor needs its base current to be sunk in order to operate. I expect the OPAMP to be an open collector to draw that current.

Comment: the opamp is not an open collector, but it can indeed sink and source current. Don't overthink the closed-loopness of the opamp: the current/V_BE curve of that transistor is very nonlinear, so that's not very easy to understand or even model numerically. Try to abstract a bit in terms of "what happens when...":  When I_sense increases, the voltage across R_sense increases, thus U_sense increases, and hence, Vin+ - Vin- of the opamp decreases, decreasing the opamp output voltage, hence sinking transistor base current, hence increasing the current flow through the transistor, hence reducing V_CE

Comment: of the transistor, hence pulling Vfb up. Done!"

Comment: Thanks Marcus, these two last comments are very helpful

Comment: Try read this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/458384/cc-cv-buck-controller/458446#458446 and this http://powersupply.blogs.keysight.com/2012/07/how-does-power-supply-regulate-its.html

Comment: Thanks G36, I finally got what I want, Because of your comment I could analyse the circuit and answered my own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search and contribution from internet, I could finally understand the principle of controlling a transistor through an OPAMP (the OPAMP takes whatever it costs to make vin- equls to Vin+). I provide below a simple solution to my question:
[image]