# Buck converter programable CC with DAC

Tags: battery-charging, dc-dc-converter, buck, dac

I am trying to implement a programable CC (Constant current) functionality into the utilized buck converter (AP64501SP-13). The converter is to be used for series cells charging. I need to be able to set the charging current with highest resolution possible.

I have stumbled upon the voltage to current converter circuit from this post: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/458446/59894

It would fit just fine if I was able to replace the `RB` with a digital potentiometer. I went that path and the current programming resolution is too low. I have an MCU with on board 12 bit DAC and a 0.1 % 2.048 V reference source and would like to use that. I was initially thinking about modifying the circuit this way:

[image]

But something tells me there is a better way. I would appreciate all help.

Comment: If you put the shunt resistor in the negative path of the load you have less noise, because the shunt is not in direct contact with the output ripple voltage. You can amplify the shunt voltage with a current sense amplifier like INA181 or NCS199. With a second OpAmp you can compare the DAC output to the sensed current and e.g. pull the soft start input voltage down. This, however, will fail if the converter enters burst mode. The AP64501SP is not a good starting point for a CC circuit with "highest resolution possible". There are other chips designed for that task.

Comment: Thanks. The shunt resistor needs to be in the high side, since the ground is shared with the rest of the circuitry and cannot be broken. Otherwise I would go for that. Can you suggest the better chip?